# Recursively call function to get folder in order MySQL

Tags: mysql

Mysql Query to find out what all the `c:` values are:

```
id  name        parent_id
1   c:          null
2   Users           1
3   programfile     1
4   profile         2
5   d:          null
6   projects        5
7   ali         6
```

output:

```
    c:/
    c:/Users
    c:/Users/profile
    c:/programfile
```

Query I tried:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( 
    SELECT
        id,
        id nextid,
        parent_id
    FROM
        folder AS t1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte.id,
        t2.id, 
        t2.parent_id
    FROM
        folder AS t2
        JOIN cte ON cte.parent_id = t2.id 
)
SELECT
    Id,
    nextid RootId
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    parent_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: So what is your question? And what happens when you run your query?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP_CONCAT( name ORDER BY depth SEPARATOR '\\' )` - and you'll need to update your query to calculate each folder's `depth` too.

Comment: *Query I tried* Your query iterates over the rows hierarchy, but does not collect current node path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, 
           CAST(name AS CHAR(65535)) fqpath
    FROM folder
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT folder.id, folder.name, folder.parent_id, 
           CONCAT_WS('/', cte.fqpath, folder.name)
    FROM cte
    JOIN folder ON cte.id = folder.parent_id
)
SELECT id, name, parent_id, 
       CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL
            THEN CONCAT(fqpath, '/')
            ELSE fqpath
            END fqpath
FROM cte;
```